# Next.js fileUploading issue during responsive

Tags: next.js

I created seperate component in my Next.js application for fileupload its working properly with all screens but in actual mobile fileupload dialogue box is not open .
what to do and how to fix it

I need a solution like file uploading should work as it in the localhost into the file server

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.